# Do native mobile apps need a web server?

Tags: python, ios, rest, mobile, webserver

I want to create a native iOS app. It will have a database in the backend to store data. I want to use Python to create REST APIs so that the front end can use the APIS to add data to database. I am debating if I need a web server for this app. My questions are:
Do native mobile apps typically use web servers like Apache or Nginx for their backend? Aren't web servers suppose to deliver just static web content?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able, it would be a lot easier to store your data in an on-device database using something like SQLite. However, if you need to store this data off device/in the cloud, setting up a webserver and REST APIs that control a database is a very normal design. "Web Server" is a pretty loose term and could describe a server that serves static content, processes API calls, or both.

You can also use "serverless architecture" where setting up the actual webserver is abstracted away. For example, AWS's [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) lets you set up REST API's that send requests to a variety of AWS database products without having to worry about setting up apache or something similar. If you're planning on hosting your backend in AWS, this is a good option to consider.